# Next.js Reload on Save

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Currently my application, running on next and built with React, only reloads when I run `next build` and restart the server. Why is this happening, how do I reload without having to do a production build?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#development

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running `next dev` or `npm run dev` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it also happen when error occured. check log (npm run dev) if there is any error fix it.